# how can i replace two subtitles in a mkv file?

Tags: ffmpeg

i have an mkv file with 2 audio and 4 subtitle streams. the 3rd and 4th subtitle stream contained errors, so i extracted and corrected them, but i don't know how i can replace them in the mkv file. i tried
`ffmpeg.exe -i .\video.mkv -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 0:3 -map 0:4 -i sub1.srt -i sub2.srt out.mkv`

but this gives me the error:

```
Option map (set input stream mapping) cannot be applied to input url sub2.srt -- you are trying to apply an input option to an output file or vice versa. Move this option before the file it belongs to.
Error parsing options for input file sub2.srt.
Error opening input files: Invalid argument
```

can anyone tell me the correct command?

Answer (score 2):

Option location is important:

```
ffmpeg [input0 options] -i input0 [input1 options] -i input1 [output options] output
```

So you are attempting to apply `-map` options to `sub1.srt`.

Use:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -i sub1.srt -i sub2.srt -map 0 -map -0:s:2 -map -0:s:3 -map 1 -map 2 -c copy out.mkv
```

Option description:

- `-map 0`  (`ffmpeg` file index starts at 0) selects all streams from `video.mkv`.
- `-map -0:s:2` negative map that deselects subtitle #3.
- `-map -0:s:3` negative map that deselects subtitle #4.
- `-map 1` selects all streams from `sub1.srt`.
- `-map 2` selects all streams from `sub2.srt`.
- `-c copy` [stream copies](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) all streams. Does not re-encode.